An interesting two-person game theory problem on an $n \times n$ grid
Here's an interesting game theory problem I once saw on the internet:

Let $n \ge 2$ be a positive integer. Consider the set $V_n \subseteq \mathbb{Z^2}$ defined as $V_n := \{ (x,y) : 1 \le x,y \le n\}.$ This set represents an $n \times n$ grid.  Two mathematicians $A$ and $B$ decide to play a game on the $n \times n$ grid  with the following rules. The game begins with player $A$ choosing a pair of adjacent vertices (i.e. separated by a unit distance in the euclidean plane)  and connecting them with an edge. The players alternate turns thereafter, with player $A$ only allowed to choose and join two unconnected adjacent vertices that both have degrees of the same parity, and player $B$ only allowed to choose and join two unconnected adjacent vertices with degrees of different parity in their respective turns. The game ends when no legal moves remain, and the player unable to make the move in his turn loses. Is there an optimal strategy for either player to ensure victory ? (Note that the degree of a vertex $v$ is the number of edges incident on $v$)

I naturally tried to approach the problem by taking smaller values of $n$. For $n = 2$, it is clear that player $B$ always wins. But I am pretty much stuck for $n = 3$, where I really can't find any optimal strategy or something close enough. Hence any hints on how to proceed for $n = 3$ will be highly appreciated as it will provide some insight for the general case.
You can use the following notations while describing the solutions. Let $A_i$ denote the edge chosen by player $A$ on his $i^{th}$ turn. Similarly define $B_i$. You can also describe the sequence of edges by mapping $V_n$ to all positive integers from $1$ to $n^2$ in a row-wise fashion and describing each edge using tuples $(a,b)$ where $1 \le a,b \le n^2$.
You can also use an $n \times n$ matrix with each entry describing the degree of the vertex at each stage if needed.

What does "parity" mean here?

parity is about numbers being odd or even. Numbers with same parity are either both even or both odd and those different parity have one odd and the other even

But here you're talking about the parity of the vertices and it's not clear to me what that means.

@QuantumWiz the OP is talking about parities of degrees of vertices.

@Pranay Ah, right. I had somehow missed that part.

Perhaps I’m misunderstanding but… say A picked vertices u and v. In B’s first turn, B must pick one of the vertices A picked, say v, and another previously unpicked vertex, say w. But then A can pick the u and w to form a cycle. Now B has no legal move.

The player can only choose vertices separated by a unit distance , i.e. either horizontally or vertically. u and w will be √2 units apart.

Ah okay. I thought that restriction was only for A’s first turn.

Sorry about that I have edited the problem now.

If I am understanding right your description of the ruleset:
Imagine anywhere in the $n \times n$ grid, an arbitrary $2$ by $2$ grid, still in its initial state of $0,0,0,0$. Player $A$ must be the first to draw an edge inside this grid, for $B$ has no possible moves inside it yet.
Player $B$ then draws their edge within this grid, too, at a right angle to Player $A$’s edge. And in so doing, $A$ can never have more edges inside this grid than B.
If this strategy is applied the entire game, eventually the players will reach a corner of the $n \times n$ grid. In the corners, Player $A$ cannot create two edges if Player $B$ had been employing this strategy the entire game.
Player $B$ therefore can ensure placing $4$ extra more edges than Player $A$ whenever the game has finished, which is just another way of saying Player $A$ ran out of moves before Player $B$.

Can you explain how this strategy works for example on a $3\times3$? In your strategy, do you only consider one $2\times2$ subgrid of it or four? If the latter, each internal edge belongs to two $2\times2$ subgrids, so which should B be looking at, and how does that affect the other one?

Even if a $2\times2$ subgrid has its four edges still unplayed, those vertices could already have other edges to vertices outside that grid, so the vertices might not have only zero degree vertices. How does that affect the strategy?

I think I tend to agree with @JaapScherphuis here.
